# IOS 6 Update code error switching views

Tags: ios5, uiview, ios6, self, xcode4.5

im designing a app thats a single view application and i am adding the code so that i can switch views via a button but every-time i enter my code that was working in IOS 5 it now comes up with a error ? heres the code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController 


- (IBAction)home:(id)sender;


@end




#import "ViewController1.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1


- (IBAction)home:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *second =[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

heres the error

[image]

thank you!!
edited answers my errors now ??
[image]

[image]

[image]

by the way i really appreciate it and i will give you good tick by your answer once done this is the errors now??

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not an error but it is warning.

And for help you can read the documents provided by Apple.

And to remove that warning just use the below code

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Comment: are you sure thats correct because it comes up with more errors ??

Comment: Btw what errors are shown please explain them or edit in your question :)

Comment: see the edit have to remove the comment from { } bracts then this will remove the all errors

Comment: ok alos remove the < char before ^ char it is not required it is typo from me sorry :)

Comment: Have to enclose the whole statement in [ ] brackets see the answer edited by me  :)

Comment: sorry it has its all mint now thank you very much one last thing before you go how and where did you learn code ??